# ObjectListView is ignoring Dragging effect

Tags: c#, objectlistview

Hello I'm using ObjectListView for my application. I try to make a fancy drag effect because the original blue one is not so good. It's like highlighting the first column when I drag. I was using this on my normal listview

```
        private void lvPlaylist_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Point mLoc = lvPlaylist.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            var hitt = lvPlaylist.HitTest(mLoc);
            if (hitt.Item == null) return;

            int idx = hitt.Item.Index;
            if (idx == prevItem) return;

            lvPlaylist.Refresh();
            using (Graphics g = lvPlaylist.CreateGraphics())
            {
                Rectangle rect = lvPlaylist.GetItemRect(idx);
                Pen MyPen = new Pen(Color.OrangeRed, 3);
                g.DrawLine(MyPen, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Top);
            }
            prevItem = idx;
        }
```

But it's not working in ObjectListView. Well actually it does but when I stop to drag but not releasing my dragging objects it's showing me that blue default drag effect while I keep moving I see my own drag effect. Is there any way to disable OLV Drag effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution draws a line above/below the item being selected?

You can allow dropping between using:

```
lvPlaylist.IsSimpleDropSink = true;
((SimpleDropSink)lvPlaylist.DropSink).CanDropBetween = true;
```

If this is not good enough you can respond to `ModelCanDrop` e.g.

```
//((SimpleDropSink)lvPlaylist.DropSink).ModelCanDrop+= ModelCanDrop;

 private void ModelCanDrop(object sender, ModelDropEventArgs e)
 {
     e.DropSink.Billboard.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
     e.DropSink.FeedbackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
     e.InfoMessage = "Hey there";
     e.Handled = true;
     e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
 }
```

If you really hate it that much you can even:

```
e.DropSink.EnableFeedback = false;
```

The ObjectListView site has a great indepth tutorial on drag and drop:

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/blog4.html#blog-rearrangingtreelistview

If you want to go for something really fancy you can write your own subclass for SimpleDropSink:

```
lvPlaylist.IsSimpleDragSource = true;
lvPlaylist.DropSink = new MyDropSink();

private class MyDropSink : SimpleDropSink
{
    public override void DrawFeedback(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds)
    {
        if(DropTargetLocation != DropTargetLocation.None)
            g.DrawString("Heyyy stuffs happening",new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 10),new SolidBrush(Color.Magenta),bounds.X,bounds.Y );
    }
}
```

For your desired behaviour you should try something like:

```
private class MyDropSink : SimpleDropSink
{
    private ObjectListView _olv;

    public MyDropSink(ObjectListView olv)
    {
        _olv = olv;
    }

    public override void DrawFeedback(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds)
    {
        if(DropTargetLocation != DropTargetLocation.None)
        {
            Point mLoc = _olv.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            var hitt = _olv.HitTest(mLoc);
            if (hitt.Item == null) return;

            int idx = hitt.Item.Index;
            Rectangle rect = _olv.GetItemRect(idx);
            Pen MyPen = new Pen(Color.OrangeRed, 3);
            g.DrawLine(MyPen, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Top);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know the bilboard and the feedback that OLV is supporting but the problem is I don't want them, my code above draw a line between 2 listview item for the whole row. OLV does this too but only to the selected item. If I set CanDropOnItem property to true and CanDropBetween I get this blue line between my items.But my own code that I have write for a regular listview draw this line between "rows" not "items". I thought maybe I could override or close OLV's draw event so I can use my own code to draw while I do drag and drop

Comment: What about writting your own class inheriting `DropSink` and and overriding `DrawFeedback`? You should be able to draw any line you want in that method.  I've found that working with OLV is a lot easier than working against it.

Comment: I know that feeling, I've tried to work against it and I failed multiple times but I want my own row color when I do drag and drop. Does OLV paint that blue color in DrawFeedback? if so maybe I can inherit OLV and override it as you say

Comment: You can paint whatever you like I think.  You only need to inherit the DropSink which is a subcomponent that handles drag and drop.  I'll update my post

Comment: I have paste my code inside DrawFeedback but looks like it's same. In fact now I have to move my mouse even faster to see my own red color drawing. Originally I was using my method inside DragOver method. I have also tried to override it as empty method then I was able to see my red line untill I stop. Once I stop like before it is dissappearing somehow. But thank you atleast I could get rid of that blue OLV drag effect

Comment: I've tested your code in DrawFeedback and it looks like the issue is calling `Refresh` and trying to not drawing when `idx == prevItem`.  Basically olv will spam the DrawFeedback so if you are not drawing constantly then your pic will disapear.  I updated the original post with the working implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your update. I was trying to overriding over after your first edit. I thought DrawFeedback is not the correct event but seems like it is! Thanks again for your effort I appreciate it